# Subsitute of "around 19 years back"?

Tags: phrase-usage

In a presentation I have to say " around 19 years before", But I don't want to say number "19".

Could anyone suggest some alternate phrase ??

e.g. "Couple of years back ??"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word to use here is "ago"

"Couple" means "two", not 19.  "Around 19" means "About 20" or two decades. So you can avoid 19 by saying

> About twenty years ago...
>   A couple of decades ago...

Or a more radical rephrasing

> In the late 1990s...

Comment: I would make that specifically **two decades**. The margin for *about 19 years* is a couple of years, not a decade or more.

Comment: I wrote "A couple of decades" and not "About a couple decades" for that reason.